# How to Index Values From a where Condition Tuple in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the first and last element of a tuple created from a where condition. I am getting stuck because all of the values satisfying the where condition are stored in the 0th index of `s_time_ind` rather than have 0,1,2,...,48 indices.

These are the first values of interest in the time array. There are 1111 values and they are float64 type.

```
769     7.000000
770     7.001389
771     7.002778
772     7.004167
773     7.005556
774     7.006944
775     7.008333
776     7.009722
777     7.011111
778     7.012500
779     7.013889
780     7.015278
781     7.016667
782     7.018056
783     7.019444
784     7.020833
785     7.022222
786     7.023611
787     7.025000
788     7.026389
789     7.027778
790     7.029167
791     7.030556
792     7.031944
793     7.033333
794     7.034722
795     7.036111
796     7.037500
797     7.038889
798     7.040278
799     7.041667
800     7.043056
801     7.044444
802     7.045833
803     7.047222
804     7.048611
805     7.050000
806     7.051389
807     7.052778
808     7.054167
809     7.055556
810     7.056944
811     7.058333
812     7.059722
813     7.061111
814     7.062500
815     7.063889
816     7.065278
817     7.066667
```

This is the condition I have coded and it is printing the correct indices that I need but it's storing them in the 0th index of `s_time_ind` so I can't pull out the first and last index by doing `s_time_ind[0]` to get `769` and `s_time_ind[48]` to get `817`.

```
s_time_ind = np.where((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))
print(s_time_ind)

(array([769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781,
       782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794,
       795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807,
       808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817], dtype=int64),)
```

When I enter `print(s_time_ind[0])`  I get all of the values.

```
[769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780 781 782 783 784 785 786
 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804
 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817]
```

And when I enter `print(s_time_ind[1])` or any value greater than 0 I get the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-b4a0e1537e07> in <module>
      1 s_time_ind = np.where((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))
----> 2 print(s_time_ind[1])

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I want to be able to enter `s_time_ind[0]` and get `769` and `s_time_ind[48]` to get `817`.

Comment: While the question has a whole bunch of extra information, I want to commend you for making a complete and thorough post. You did a good job of creating an MCVE and walking me through exactly what you were trying to do and what you were thinking. As your experience grows, your terminology and ability to eliminate superfluous fluff will get better, but you are already on the right track. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you so much for your kind words and excellent explanation! It means a lot as I am relatively new to Python and am working hard to learn.

Comment: Glad to help. I can tell you're new, but it's nice that you're clearly putting in the work. I see too many people on this site asking for "free codez" instead of doing their homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns a python `tuple` with one array per dimension. You happen to have a 1D array, so you are not noticing that the result is surrounded in parentheses:

```
(array([...], dtype=int64),)
```

Notice the comma at the end. That comma tells you that the outer parentheses represent a `tuple`, not just casual grouping.

The result you are looking for is the array in the beginning of the tuple. You can extract it by doing:

```
s_time_ind = np.where((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))
s_time_ind = s_time_ind[0]   # Now s_time_ind is the array of indices, not a tuple
```

More concisely:

```
s_time_ind = np.where((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))[0]
```

Since the one-arg version of `np.where` is a wrapper for [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), it's better to use the latter for indexing a mask:

```
s_time_ind = np.nonzero((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))[0]
```

The best option is to use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) for one-dimensional arrays:

```
s_time_ind = np.flatnonzero((time >= 7.000000) & (time <= 7.066667))
```

No extracting necessary this way.